# Writing two functions side by side instead of writing one down the another one.

Tags: align

I have two functions (each defined by two rules). I want to write each couple of them side by side instead of writing them down each others. Is that possible ?

My code is:

```
\begin{document}


 \begin{enumerate}[nolistsep]\item[(i)] 
 \begin{align*}
 f(x)=
 \begin{cases}
 \frac{\sqrt{3+x}-\sqrt{3} }{x}; &\text{$x\neq 0$}, \\
 \frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}; &\text{$x=0$}
 \end{cases}.
 \end{align*}
 \item[(ii)] 
 \begin{align*}
 f(x)= 
 \begin{cases}
 \frac{1-\cos 2x}{2x^2}; &\text{$x\neq 0$}, \\
   2; &\text{$x=0$}
  \end{cases}.
   \  end{align*}

   \end{enumerate}.
```

The output of this code is as follows: 
  [image]

but i want them to be written as follows:
[image].

What modifications should i do to my code ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please, provide a working MWE. Your code yields a bunch of errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `tasks` package for that:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}%
\usepackage{tasks}

\begin{document}

\begin{tasks}[counter-format = (tsk[r]), label-width = 2em, label-align = right, label-offset = 0.6em, item-indent =2.8em, column-sep = 1.5em](2)
  \task $f(x)=
    \begin{dcases}
      \frac{\sqrt{3+x}-\sqrt{3} }{x},  & x \neq 0 , \\
      \frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}, & x=0
    \end{dcases}$

  \task $ f(x)=
    \begin{dcases}
      \frac{1-\cos 2x}{2x^2}, & x \neq 0, \\
      2, & x=0
    \end{dcases}$

  \task $ f(x)=
    \begin{dcases}
      \frac{[x]}{x}, & x \neq 0, \\
      1,& x=0
    \end{dcases}$

  \task $ f(x)=
    \begin{dcases}
      \frac{|x|}{x}, & x \neq 0, \\
      1, & x=0
    \end{dcases}$
\end{tasks}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: if the counters weren't italic, it wouldn't look so much like they are part of the formulas.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: I know, but that seemed to be the O.P.'s requirement.

Comment: Excuse me but i have some final question: the counters (i), (ii), (iii) and (iv) look italic, how can i write them in a non-italic forms?
@Bernard

Comment: I made them italic because they were so in the image you posted. To have them in roman remove the `$ ... $`, like this:`counter-format = (tsk[r])`

Comment: You're welcome, @HusseinEid

Comment: I have some another question please: Is it possible to decrease or even increase the distance between two items down each others ? 
@Bernard

Comment: @bernard : how to set a tag to a particular task and make a reference later in the document using this tag?